# Access Sinatra settings from a model

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a modular Sinatra app. I'm setting some custom variables in my configure block and want to access these settings in my model.

The problem is, I get a `NoMethodError` when I try and access my custom settings from `MyModel`. Standard settings still seem to work fine though. How can I make this work?

```
# app.rb
require_relative 'models/document'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :resource_path, '/xfiles/i_want_to_believe'
  end

  get '/' do
    @model = MyModel.new
    haml :index
  end
end

# models/my_model.rb
class MyModel
  def initialize
    do_it
  end
  def do_it
    ...
    settings.resource_path # no method error
    ...
    settings.root # works fine
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not pass in the setting as an argument? It seems like poor separation of concerns to directly reference `settings` in the model.

Comment: That's a fair point. The setting is a path, pointing to the apps resources (the model wraps these files). I want some rails-like methods so I can go `@m = MyModel.find "name_of_resource"` and have it work. I'd rather not use `MyModel.find "name_of_resource", settings.resource_path` all the time. I'd also rather keep the find method as part of the model instead of a helper. Perhaps I'm fighting Sinatra here...

Comment: +1 for passing it as an argument. The least thing it can do is making testing the `do_it` method easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
#document.rb
class Document
  def self.documents_path=(path)
    @documents_path = path
  end
  def self.documents_path
    @documents_path
  end
  ...
end

#app.rb
configure do
  set :documents_path, settings.root + "/../documents/" 
  Document.documents_path = settings.documents_path
end
```

then just using Document.documents_path inside my find method.

Answer (score 15):

i think that you should be able to access it via

```
Sinatra::Application.settings.documents_path
```

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality post, because your answer contains one single line. Some visitors want to know more details about your solution.

Comment: and yet, Reporter, the 1 line answer was PERFECTLY appropriate to a question whose answer was the correct syntax.