# Access Sinatra (classic style) settings from models outside main file

Tags: ruby, sinatra, upgrade

I'm upgrading a Sinatra ("classic" style) app to latest released version, from 1.3.3 to 1.4.6. I also use `config_file` from `sinatra-contrib` (also upgraded from 1.3.2 to 1.4.6) with multi-environments.

My config file (`config/app.yml`) looks like:

```
development: &defaults
  console_username: admin
  console_password: secret

test:
  <<: *defaults

staging:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

On the other hand, I have some POROs under `lib/`. Before the upgrade, I can access to the `settings` inside those classes under `lib/`, but now I can't. In summary, previously I can do something like:

```
settings.console_username
```

After the upgrade, I need to access these variables by:

```
Sinatra::Application.console_username
```

I reviewed the changelog but I can't find this change documented, am I missing something?

PS: I also found this: [Access Sinatra settings from a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735622/access-sinatra-settings-from-a-model). I'm agree with the last answer, probably is a better idea to decouple this thing, and pass the settings to the class.

Comment: I think this commit may be responsible: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/commit/46bdb7dcf842afdb3bce57a6753eb4d909b1225d